# How to use vuelidate with vuetify 2 for nested data? Getting invalid field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I'm trying to use vuelidate with Vuetify 2 but im getting into trouble when trying to validate a nested object value.

This code works fine:

```
    <template>
        <v-text-field
        v-model="no_nome"
        :error-messages="nameErrors"
        label="Nome"
        @input="$v.no_nome.$touch()"
        @blur="$v.no_nome.$touch()"
        >
        </v-text-field>
    </template>

    <script>

     import { required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
     export default {

        data() {
            return {
                no_nome:'',
            }
        },
        validations: {
            no_nome: {
                required
            },
        },
        computed: {
            nameErrors () {
                const errors = []
                if (!this.$v.no_nome.$dirty)
                    return errors
                !this.$v.no_nome.required && errors.push('Name is required.')
                return errors
            },
        }
     }
   </scrip>
```

But if i change my `no_nome` data to:

```
        data() {
            return {
                user : {
                   no_nome:'',
                }
            }
        },
```

and

```
        <v-text-field
        v-model="user.no_nome"
        :error-messages="nameErrors"
        label="Nome"
        @input="$v.no_nome.$touch()"
        @blur="$v.no_nome.$touch()"
        >
        </v-text-field>
```

after running `$vm0.$v.no_nome.$touch()`, `$vm0.$v.no_nome.$invalid` will always return `true` even when `user.no_nome` is not empty. How can i make the validation works for `user.no_nome` and any other nested data value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the same data shape between your data and your validations. See [Data Nesting](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-data-nesting).

So your `validations` must be:

```js
validations: {
  user: {
    no_nome: {
      required
    }
  }
}
```

and

```js
computed: {
  nameErrors () {
    const errors = []
    if (!this.$v.user.no_nome.$dirty)
      return errors
    !this.$v.user.no_nome.required && errors.push('Name is required.')
    return errors
  }
}
```

and

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="user.no_nome"
  :error-messages="nameErrors"
  @input="$v.user.no_nome.$touch()"
  @blur="$v.user.no_nome.$touch()"/>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xd3742cy/)